# _Controller name in ASP .NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, configuration, controller, naming-conventions

In MVC 4, we'd like to keep our current naming convention which separates all words by underscores, e.g. `Store_Controller`. However, this results in the urls looking like `http://www.blah.com/Store_` which is really undesirable.

I've seen elsewhere that you can get around this with some deep mucking in the MVC framework, making your own controller factories and whatnot, but surely there's an easier way to configure this. Is there some new annotation or config setting that has been introduced over the years that existing methods don't take into account?

Comment: Yes; I don't recall what it's called offhand, but there's an attribute you can apply to action methods to indicate an alternate action name they'll respond to...

Comment: Yes I believe that works for actions, but not the controller names, which is what I'm asking about. If there's some kind of attribute one can add to the controller itself, I'm all ears!

Comment: Oh duh... sometimes I don't pay close enough attention! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MVC5, you could use [Attribute Routing](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5.aspx) for that.

But in MVC4, you can do the following (note you must do both, not one or the other):

1. Configure routes to handle this like so:

   ```
   routes.MapRoute(
       name: "Default",
       url: "Store/{action}/{id}",
       defaults: new { controller = "Store_", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional}
   );
   ```
2. Use a custom controller factory (which is easy too):

   ```
   public class CustomControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
   {
       protected override Type GetControllerType(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext, string controllerName)
       {
           return base.GetControllerType(requestContext, controllerName + "_");
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Where does this controller factory go? and how does MVC know to use it?

Comment: It can be kept in the Controllers folder of your MVC project, for example, or in a separate project (Class Library) which you reference from the MVC project. To make the framework use your custom controller factory, you can put this in your Global.asax's Application_Start(): System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new CustomControllerFactory());

Comment: Ok this seems like it will work for our purposes. I screwed up at first and misread your method, only doing #1 and not #2 and wondering why it didn't work. It wasn't clear that you must do both, so I went ahead and updated that. 

I assume I can use this method to also alter underscores in the middle of a controller name such that the URL uses dashes instead, e.g. `Store_Manager_Controller` > URL `/Store-Manager/`

Answer (score -1):

no this is not a correct pattern you cannot use "underscore" "_" to split controllername

this is the few URL:

```
mysite/{username}/{action}                  ~  /mysite/jatten/login
public/blog/{controller}-{action}/{postId}  ~ /public/blog/posts-show/123
{country}-{lang}/{controller}/{action}/{id} ~ /us-en/products/show/123
products/buy/{productId}-{productName}  ~ /products/but/2145-widgets
```